# Derivation of the vertex value of quadratic term in GLM in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, quadratic-form

I have a quadratic term in a GLM and I am interested in the vertex value (+ the standard error and confidence interval of the vertex) of the quadratic term. To my knowledge, there is no automatic function for this purpose in R, and I am unable to calculate this manually, as I do not have sufficient knowledge of statistics and R. Is there anybody who could help and build the code to derive the values of interest?

`GLM <- glm(Y ~ X1 + I(X1^2) + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, family="binomial", data=DF)`

Comment: Why not just spend a couple mins to do this manually?

Comment: @Ben Honestly I am a beginner in statistics as well as in R and I am not sure how exactly to do it

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. If you ask about a derivation, I'm sure someone will write it up. The point estimate involves some algebra and the standard error involves the delta method (i.e. taking a derivative).

Comment: Profiling the likelihood is effective.  Unless you have enormous amounts of data, you shouldn't expect the usual asymptotic (Normal distribution) results to be very accurate.  There are *huge* potential problems when the estimated vertex is near or beyond the range of `X1`.

Comment: @whuber It seems like you're content with asymptotic distributions for the coefficients (which is what `glm` gives) but not with asymptotic distributions for functions of coefficients. If so, could you elaborate on why?

Comment: @Ben It's a matter of what we might expect of the distribution.  Coefficient distributions in a linear model often are well approximated by the asymptotics, but nonlinear functions of those coefficients might not be.  There's a good basis for supposing that would be problematic here, because the sampling distribution of the vertex will be extremely skewed unless the vertex is near the middle of the range of the data.

Comment: I would say my vertex is approximately near the centre of the data range (the x-axis extent reflects the data extent). But I still don’t know how to calculate its exact position. [![Screenshot-2022-08-20-at-01-14-10.png](https://i.postimg.cc/X7G4byzt/Screenshot-2022-08-20-at-01-14-10.png)](https://postimg.cc/tYjLd7yz)

Comment: @whuber Interesting, thanks!